# Table with time series - duplicate data/rows

Tags: tables, data-tables

currently i'm facing some issues with large data tables with lots of duplicated/redundant data.

Those rows displaying time series of measurements and are mostly identical, so most of the rows looks like that:

```
1.1.2019 | 21 | "value" | "other value"
1.2.2019 | 21 | "value" | "other value"
1.3.2019 | 21 | "value" | "other value"
1.4.2019 | 21 | "value" | "other value"
1.5.2019 | 22 | "value" | "other value"
```

is there any good pattern how to reduce displayed redundant rows? Just searched a lot, but was not very successful.

```
1.1.2019 | 21 | "value" | "other value"
1.2.2019 |    |         | 
1.3.2019 |    |         | 
1.4.2019 |    |         | 
1.5.2019 | 22 |         |
```

Was my intuitive try, but first i looks kind of stupid and there might be empty fields (measurement errors).

thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: Is it for your users? If yes, do they know how data science works?
If they do, don't bother too much, they know how those kind of data works.
If they don't, find a way to display it visually maybe? Using graph or group it by the "Intra" factor that makes having them multiples times.

If you precise more your problem, I will be able to help you more!

Comment: I would put the same values in grey, so that the changed values are easily found. This assume that state remain the same (not just same measurement) but for time to time (but not regularly) the status change)

Comment: What are the field names for those values?

Answer (score 1):

You could show the dates that have the same values in a range like this, accordion-style:

```
1.1.2019 - 1.4.2019 | 21 | "value" | "other value"       (+)
1.5.2019            | 22 |         | 
1.6.2019            | 21 | "value" | "other value"       (-)
1.7.2019            | 21 | "value" | "other value"
1.8.2019            | 21 | "value" | "other value"
1.9.2019            | 21 | "value" | "other value"
```

The **(+)/(-)** would be an accordion icon to display all